# Is there a proper path for storing images (Theme and Uploads) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm relatively new to Laravel - building a basic website with it - and I'm unclear as to where I'm suppose to store images.

My instinct said `/resources/images` but that path doesn't exist like `/js` and `/css` do.

I read that `/storage/app/public/images` could be, but the answers I'm finding are inconclusive.

I understand the local may differ if they were uploaded through a GUI by an end-user vs by a developer who is creating a theme / template.

I'd like a citation to official documentation assuming one exists. Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't  taken a look at this I would recommend: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unintentionally discovered [this Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/structure) which explains the purpose of each directory. In that it states the following:

> This (`/public`) directory also houses your assets such as images, JavaScript, and CSS.

Based on the next quote it's implied the above is referring to images uploaded by the developer for the front end. Whereas the following explicitely states it's for user-generated files:

> The `/storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible.

Earlier in the documentation is makes  a subtle but, presumably, essential note:

> By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public.

@techcyclist rightly referenced [more official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) about [*how* to reference these](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#retrieving-files) in their respective locations. Such as files in the `/storage` [this way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files), and the `public` directory this way. It also mentions advanced options for storage such as Amazon S3 under "Specifying a Disk".

Comment: The keyword is `disks` declared in `config/filesystem.php`. For example, I use Amazon's S3 for all user file (pic) uploads. Swapping to another disk at anytime is a breeze in Laravel. Just change the disk 'public' to 's3' and it's done. The driver implementation takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Usually images are stored in public folder and you can easily access then with /img/somepic.jpg from anywhere in your project. Also you can store them in storage/images but then you need to use function for relative path to storage.

Answer (score 0):

**image does not exist in resources folder it exists in public folder**

**try like this, it will pick public folder default.**

```
{{url('images/image_name')}}
```